# How to accept ";' semicolon, as input, and not execute the next line of codes?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

Here's a small portion of a practice I'm doing preventing erroneous inputs.

```
while(1) {
        printf("Choose From 1 to 7 ");
        if( scanf("%d", &nNum ) != 1) { 
            printf("Please only choose from the numbers 1-7."); 
                fgets(sErraticInputs, 100 , stdin);
        } else if (nNum > 7 || nNum <= 0) {
            printf("Please only choose from the numbers 1-7.");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I was doing a good job, until I entered "6;p". It executed the 6 portion and ran correctly, but technically speaking it should have taken the whole thing as the input, and proceeded with the error message.

Comment: You asked for a number, it parsed a number and stopped when it found something that wasn't a number.

Comment: When entering input using quotes '6;q', otherwise shell will interpret ;

Comment: you can do this: `scanf("%s", stringInput)`, where `stringInput` is `char*` then write some code that validates the input string. That should be quite easy to accomplish. Test if the first `char` value is between `49` and `55` (ASCII value of 1 - 7) etc....

Comment: Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is not a good idea; better to stick with one or the other.

Comment: `scanf("%d",...)` means "read a number, stop when the number ends". That's exactly what the code does. If you want it to do something else, perhaps try to specify what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think the posted code can give the said result. The `break` statement will end the `while(1)` when `6` has been read so there will not be printed an error message.

If we assume that the `break` isn't part of your real code this is what happens:

When `scanf` is told to read an integer, it will continue reading from the input stream as long as the next character (together with the previous read characters) can be converted into an integer. As soon as the next character can not be used as part of an integer, `scanf` will stop and give you the result of what it has parsed so far.

In your case the input stream contains

```
6;p\n
```

So `scanf` will read the `6` and stop (i.e. return `6`). The input stream now contains:

```
;p\n
```

Consequently this will be the input for your next `scanf` and cause the input error, you saw.

One way to solve this would be to flush stdin after **all** `scanf` - both on success and on failure:

```
nNum = 0;
while(nNum != 7)  // Just as an example I use input 7 to terminate the loop
{
    printf("Choose From 1 to 7 ");
    if( scanf("%d", &nNum ) != 1 || nNum > 7 || nNum <= 0) 
    { 
        printf("Please only choose from the numbers 1-7."); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("Valid input %d\n", nNum);
        // ****************************  break;  
    }
    fgets(sErraticInputs, 100 , stdin);  // Always empty stdin
}
```

note: Using `fgets` with size 100 doesn't really ensure a complete flush... you should actually use a loop and continue until a `'\n'` is read.

With the change above input like `6;p` will be taken as a valid input with value 6 and the ;p will be thrown away.

If that's not acceptable, you could drop the use of `scanf` and do the parsing yourself. There are several options, e.g. `fgets` or `fgetc`

The example below uses `fgetc`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_next()
{
    int in = fgetc(stdin);
    if (in == EOF) exit(1); // Input error
    return in;
}

void empty_stdin()
{
    while(get_next() != '\n') {};
}

int main(void) {
    int in;
    int nNum = 0;
    while(nNum != 7) 
    {
        printf("Choose From 1 to 7 \n");
        in = get_next();
        if (in == '\n' || in <= '0' || in > '7')  // First input must be 1..7
        {
            printf("Please only choose from the numbers 1-7.\n"); 
            if (in != '\n') empty_stdin();
        }
        else
        {
            nNum = in - '0';
            in = get_next();
            if (in != '\n')    // Second input must be \n
            {
                printf("Please only choose from the numbers 1-7.\n"); 
                empty_stdin();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Valid input: %d\n", nNum);
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This code will only accept a number (1..7) followed by a newline

Answer (score 0):

Here's why the "whole thing" is not taken as the input. From the man pages:

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe
>   how to process the  sequence
>          of  input  characters.   If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read, and scanf()
>          returns.  A "failure" can be either of the following: input failure, meaning that input characters
>          were unavailable, or matching failure, meaning that the input was inappropriate...

[Here's](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) the full text. Have a look at [this](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3) as well.

One approach would be to read in the whole input using `fgets` and check whether the length of the input is greater than `1`. For an input of length `1`, check if the input is a number and so on...